# Oracle SQL - duplicate rows & update columns in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle SQL table whose rows I'd like to duplicate, while incrementing the id for each row and change the value of 2 columns. So the pseudo code would go so something like this:

```
for each row r in TABLE t
  new n = r
  n.id = r.id+1
  n.columnA = 12
  n.columnB = 13
  insert n into t
```

Can someone show how I would do this in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into t(id, columnA, columnB)
select id + 1, 12, 13 from t;
```